# mysql join, grouped data, and a compare?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a table of items.

And a second table of variations.

There can be multiple variations per item.

I'm attempting something like:

```
SELECT items.*, variations.id from items
JOIN variations
ON variations.item_id = items.id
WHERE variations.id IN (23,25,29)
GROUP BY items.id
```

Which would return any items that have ALL of the above variations, 23, 25 and 29.

I also need to return all the variations.id values of the returned item.ids.

I've tried a heap of different join solutions, but don't think it's the way to go. Is a subquery the answer? Any thought would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: what happens if you remove the 'group by' clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  i.*, v.id
FROM    items i
JOIN    variations v
ON      v.item_id = i.id
WHERE   (
        SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT vi.id)
        FROM    variations vi
        WHERE   vi.item_id = i.id
                AND vi.id IN (23, 25, 29)
        ) = 3
```

Comment: That's great, and you're great.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe GROUP_CONCAT(variations.item_id) will be the right choice for you (ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/group-by-functions.html)?

But im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could do by using a count(*) and HAVING, or in this case, since only 3 entries, could explicitly JOIN TWICE for the expected variations...

This uses having/count and is more efficient than using WHERE IN ( SUBSELECT ).  It prequalifies all items FIRST with ONE query, then joins that result to the items.

```
select i.*
   from
      ( select v.item_id
           from variations v
           where v.id in ( 23, 25, 29 )
           group by v.item_id
           having count(*) = 3 ) PreQualified
      JOIN Items i
         on PreQualified.Item_ID = i.id
```